# change font for io.elementary.terminal to cascadia code fails

Tags: release-hera, fonts

I have 2 VMs, one I can change the font using elementary-tweaks and works great. The font is instantly available in terminal.  The other, I change the font in the same way and nothing happens. I close the terminal and reopen and also rebooted the VM and the font is not changed. Both are same elementary os latest version with all updates. No error message.  Where could I look to see where the problem could be.  Both VMs have the same packages installed. Hera V5.1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it by directly editing the GSettings key:

```
 gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings font 'Cascadia Code 14'
```

(Or `CascadiaCode` or `cascadia code`: see the installed font name.)

Also check in the built-in Font Viewer that the font is installed correctly.